# Question about Content in "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" by David C Lay

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I'm confused about a portion mentioned in the chapter 5.4 of the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqE58.jpg

Maybe I'm mixing the two up, but why is the vector **x** in V while the vector **x** relative to B in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

If the basis for V is B, wouldn't **x** relative to B be the one in V? and **x** on its own be the one in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The vector $x$ is given to be an element of $V$. What $[x]_B$ means, is that we are writing down the coordinates of $x$ in a given basis. This will lead to a tuple of numbers, which belongs to $\mathbb R^n$.

For example, if you take the vector space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $2$, $V = \{p(t) : \deg p \leq 2\}$, then $\mathbf x = 2t^2 + 3t+5$ is a *polynomial*, hence it is an element of $V$. However, when we consider the basis of $V$ given by $\mathcal B =\{1,t,t^2\}$, then $[\mathbf x]_{\mathcal B} = [5,3,2]$ is the representation of $\mathbf x$ in the basis $\mathcal B$, which is a series of numbers. This series of numbers belongs in $\mathbb R^3$.

So, $\mathbf x$ is a vector : an element of a vector space, so the nature of $\mathbf x$ is prescribed by the nature of $V$ : if $V$ contains polynomials, then $\mathbf x$ is a polynomial, for example. However, in a given basis, $\mathbf x$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination of the basis elements, and the unique coefficients together form a tuple of real numbers (or , a member of $\mathbb R^n$) which describes $\mathbf x$ in the given basis.